# How to display multiple forms through a view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, creating a website which has multiple forms(mostly check boxes) that need to be filled to submit a task.
Models.py

```
class M1(models.Model):
  T1=model.NullBooleanField()
  T2= model.NullBooleanField()
class M2(models.Model):
  N1=model.NullBooleanField()
  N2= model.NullBooleanField()
```

Forms.py`

```
class M1Form((forms.ModelForm): 
  class Meta: 
     model = M1 
     fields = ['T1','T2']
     widgets=.........
 class M2Form((forms.ModelForm): 
   class Meta: 
     model = M2 
     fields = ['N1','N2']
     widgets=.........
```

views.py

```
   def home_page(request):
       tmpl_vars = { 
       'form': M1Form        
    }    
    return render(request, 'my_app/test.html',tmpl_vars)
```

My question is I'm not clear on how to load the forms of M2Form through the views.py. Right now m trying to access it on the webpage and currently only the M1Form variables are visible.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is complicated. You're passing M1Form to the template vars, why can't you also pass M2Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need detailed explanation, comment of Daniel Reseman means to write in views.py

```
def home_page(request):
   tmpl_vars = { 
       'form': M1Form,
       'form2': M2Form,
   }    
   return render(request, 'my_app/test.html',tmpl_vars)
```

Then in template you can use it as `{{form2}}`

Comment: if Invalid syntax, I need to see how do you wirte in views.py exactly (write in bottom of question), or it solved?

Comment: its solved  added ()    ->              'form': M1Form(),
       'form2': M2Form (),